# Workflow Rule Update to Weed Out Specific Users

Tags: workflow, opportunity, automation, email-alert, workflowrule

We have a workflow rule in place to send an email alert to our Sales Leadership team when an Opportunity of certain record type is Closed Won. I need to modify this workflow rule to not send the alert when Opportunities owned by 2 specific users are closed won.

I modified the workflow rule to the criteria and logic in the picture below. However, the email alert is still going out when Opportunities are closed won by Christian  or Shelli.

Is there something I am doing wrong? I thought this would be easy, but I'm not sure what the issue is. Thank you all so much for taking a look.

[image]

Comment: Should be: `...AND 3 AND 4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a logical improvement on the user conditions.

Please change the rule criteria for  Christian and Shelli with "EQUALS"

Let us try with the following filter logic

1 AND 2 AND (NOT (3 OR 4))

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!